# Use many C++ DLL with the same Swig generated C# interface in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, swig, dllimport

I have few DLL's and every of them has the same interface(in body make diffrent things), I generated SWIG interface and everything work perfectly. The question is How to use this one interface for few DLL's and do it in runtime?
I want to give user posibility to load new DLL with specified structure in runtime. 
How to solve this problem without changing and multiplying DLLPinvoke.cs file?

Thanks in advance.